# How to fix patchy grass from pet urine

Tags: grass, dog

We have bald patches in the grass from pet urine recently. Looking for the best product/routine to fix this, and also maintain it?

Answer (score 1):

Product? Water, to dilute the urine, applied as soon as possible after the pet urinates on the lawn.

Routine? Don't let the pet urinate on the lawn, or at least on the parts of the lawn you want to look good.

Alternate product - AstroTurf.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can buy pet-proof grass seed.
2. The problem with dog pee is the concentration of nitrogen that it contains.  Effectively, it over-fertilises the grass.  Hence you'll see a burned area that is surrounded by rich, fast growing, dark green circle around it (too high a concentration in the middle, helpful concentration around it).  Pouring water on the pee (ideally before before it dries) will dilute the fertiliser and give you a chance of avoiding the burned area.  Adding a detergent (washing up liquid) will help the dilution - but is deadly for soil fauna (so avoid).